# Readline hanging after first input in terminal

Tags: node.js, readline

Using Node version 8.1.0.

Was reading the documentation on readline: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/readline.html

States the the close method and it states:

> The readline.Interface instance should be considered to be "finished"
>   once the 'close' event is emitted.

So naturally I would open a new interface, like I've done in my example.

```
const readline = require('readline');

function question(question, defaultAnswer) {
    // Create the interface
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rl.question(question, (answer) => {
            // Relinquished control over the input and output streams
            rl.close();
            if (answer.length === 0) {
                resolve(defaultAnswer);
            } else {
                resolve(answer);
            }
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    let answer;
    answer = await question('1? [y] ', 'y');
    console.log('answer', answer);
    answer = await question('2? [y] ', 'y');
    console.log('answer', answer);
    answer = await question('3? [y] ', 'y');
    console.log('answer', answer);
})();
```

Output:

```
$ node test.js
1? [y] y
answer y
2? [y]
```

It hangs however. I have no idea why? Currently sitting on a Mac unfortunately, I don't know if this might affect this.

Comment: I have tested your code on my Mac with node version 9.1.0. Everythings working fine. Nothing hangs here.

Comment: I'm running Sierra 10.12.6, too. But node should be independent from the OS. You could try to update your node version to v9.2.0. There haven't been made any changes on the readline lib from 9.0.0 to 9.2.0. But maybe there have been made some changes on other libs that affect the functionalities of readline.

Answer (score 1):

So I filed a bug report here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/17495

This is a known issue with Node 8.1.0. Changing from 8.1.0 to any other version made it work.